# Converting a Person's Height from feet and inches to just inches C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

Am using an external API that requests a person's height in inches, so 5.10" (5 feet and 10 inches) would be 70", now i want to give the user an input box so they can type 5.10 and then convert it to 70 in order to pass it to the API. I think there is a straight forward solution which is to:

1. truncate input towards 0
2. convert it from feet to inches
3. get the mantissa
4. convert it to int
5. add both

but i think it may not be that simple, please point me in the right direction. Coding it should pose no problem it the details and validation of input, for instance what will happen if the user type 5.12 or 5.13 for instance

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Can't you do something like: split based on `.`, convert both to int, multiply split[0] by 12, and sum everything?

Comment: Indeed. You really don't want to treat "5.10" as a single decimal value - otherwise it's exactly the same as "5.1".

Comment: i haven't done any code yet, i want to wait until the conversion is clear, in any case i doesn't seem to complicated if it's just the way i posted in my question, the one thing keeping me from implementing it right now are things like the one @JonSkeet just pointed out, are there any more of those

Comment: @Luiso Edited my answer. Please accept the one you find most useful, and mark it as the answer.

Comment: I've never seen feet & inches written with a decimal point that way. What is the application domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this will help:

```
// assuming we have string inputStr
string[] tokens = inputStr.Split ('.');
if (tokens.Length < 2 || tokens.Length > 2)
{
    throw new ArgumentException ();
}

int feet = int.Parse (tokens[0]);
int inches = int.Parse (tokens[1]);
if (inches >= 12)
{
    throw new ArgumentException ();
}

int totalInches = (feet * 12) + inches;
```

This should work, didn't test it. You will want to add error handling, too.

Comment: Feet x 12?  Also, I'm a big fan of TryParse.

Answer (score 2):

So if the user types in 5. 10, you can parse it like this to get feet and inches :

```
string userInput = "5. 10";
int feet = Convert.ToInt32(userInput.Substring(0, userInput.IndexOf(".")));
int inches = Convert.ToInt32(userInput.Substring(userInput.IndexOf(".") + 1).Trim())
```

And then do the math

```
return (feet * 12) + inches;
```

You'll obviously want to do extensive error handling to ensure the user's input is in the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
private int toInches(string input)
{
    if (input.Contains("."))
    {
        string sfeet = input.Split('.')[0];
        string sinches = input.Split('.')[1];
        int feet, inches;
        if (int.TryParse(sfeet, out feet) && int.TryParse(sinches, out inches))
        {
            return feet*12 + inches;
        }
        throw new Exception("The input is invalid");
    }
    else
    {
        int output;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out output))
        {
            return output*12;
        }
        throw new Exception("The input is invalid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
        double _Weight_pound = 135;
        int _Height_feet = 5;
        int _Height_inch = 2;
        int _Height = 0;
        double _BMI = 0;

        try { _Height = (_Height_feet * 12) + _Height_inch; } catch { }
        try { _BMI = Math.Round((_Weight_pound / (_Height * _Height)) * 703,2); } catch { }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: The question asks "how to properly parse input and convert feet&inches to just inches", and this code does not parse input, but... calculates BMI for some reason? I would not say it answers the question.